# Product Price Comparison Algo

Tags: php, solr, sphinx

I am working on price comparison website, I am done with scrap all the stores product data (around 200+), Now I am facing the

issue to show the data.

The problem is every store has its unique title of product like

For example **Google Nexus 5**

- Nexus 5
- Google Nexus 5
- LG nexus 5
- Google LG Nexus 5

or complicated example for **Canon 5D Mark III**

- Canon EOS 5D Mark III 24-105mm Lens Kit (22 Megapixels, DSLR Camera,
  Black)
- Canon EOS 5D MARK III + 24-105mm IS Lens
- Canon EOS 5D Mark III DSLR Camera (Body Only)
- Canon EOS 5D Mark III Kit (EF 24-105 F4L IS USM)
- Canon DSLR Camera EOS 5D MARK III Kit with 22.3 MP and 24-105mm F4L
  IS USM Lens
- CANON 5D Mark III Body Digital Slr Camera

So on search I am not able to find out the exact matches based on title. What are the best way to scrap this data or any opensource framework which help me to show the best result based on model.

Comment: Without any code we can't see the markup of whatever you're trying to scrap and can't really answer your question. However, I'd recommend looking at https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/datamade/dedupe would make a good starting point

Comment: I have already scrap all websites data but the thing is I am not able to get related data
for example when I use Like query %string% for iPhone 6 so it also show the result of iphone 6 case and other related to this. Make categorizing for every seller website is quite hard to filter data.

Comment: it IS hard. There is no simply 'magic' algorithm. To do it completely automatically will take very sophisticated algorithms. Probably need some machine learning.

Comment: @junjoi    I have same problem what did you do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the sites you are scrapping. Some sites have exact model, just like ISBN for books. In other cases, they have their own unique model, for example Amazon uses what's called the ASIN.

So long story short, you could use fuzzy logic to try to match but if you can find an exact model hidden somewhere in the page it will be more accurate.